# Remove error class from a multiple class field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to remove a class from a multiple class using jQuery.

I am trying to remove the error class from this class containing these multiple classes.

```
$(".first current error").removeClass("error");
```

In HTML when you inspect and just delete the error class it removes the css properly. I am trying to do this in jQuery though. Is there an error in my code here?

```
<li class="first current error">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct selector would be

```
$(".first.current.error").removeClass("error");
```

Note, that there are no spaces between classes.

... while `.first current error` selector will match for example this structure:

```
<div class="first">
  <current>
    <error></error>
  </current>
</div>
```

This is not your case, or course.